# Add or edit a model in form CRM/opportunity

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I have an Odoo 11 with CRM installed.

I created 3 fields (type Selection) and added to the view from *edit form view* in CRM / opportunity.

I have to create a dependency between the 3 drop-down (The first drop-down value limits the second drop-down and the same with the second and the third).

I think that I can do the model code. Here my problem, can not able to find or add a model to the form view.

EDIT:

I found advanced properties in fields.
In advanced properties of x_selectionb I added in *Dependencies* x_selectiona and in *Compute*:

```
a = [('c','c'),('d','d')]
b = [('e','e'),('f','f')]
for record in self:
    if record.x_selectiona == 'a':
        record.x_selectionb = fields.Selection(a)
    elif record.selectiona == 'b':
        record.x_selectionb = fields.Selection(b)
```

And i get the next error:

```
raise ValueError("forbidden opcode(s) in %r: %s" % (expr, ', '.join(opname[x] for x in codes)))
```

How I can add the values that I wanted in second Selection after select an option of the first?

I realised that I am accessing to the value in *self.x_selectionb*, not the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I created 3 models (x_modelA, x_modelB, x_modelC).

- x_modelA: x_name(char)
- x_modelB: x_name(char), x_a1(many2one related to x_modelA)
- x_modelC: x_name(char), x_b1(many2one related to x_modelB)

In opportunities I created three fields many2one (x_a, x_b, x_c).

In xml view I added the three fields:

```
<field name="x_a"/>
<field name="x_b" domain="[('x_a1', '=', x_a)]"/>
<field name="x_c" domain="[('x_b1', '=', x_b)]"/>
```

At this step the relation the dependency works, but if I change a previous drop-down, it lost the dependency.

In the field x_b (to clear values if x_a changes) I added the dependency x_a and in compute:

```
for record in self:
   record['x_b'] = False
```

In the field x_c (to clear values if x_a or x_b changes) I added the dependency x_a,x_b and in compute:

```
for record in self:
   record['x_c'] = False
```